# Windows 10 offline MTP driver installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, mtp

I installed Windows 10 and the software I needed on a computer some time back, and I now have it at my workplace, which has no internet access (or cellphone connectivity).

When I connect my Android devices to it via USB in file transfer mode, Windows doesn't recognize the device, and in the [Device Manager it shows the device under Other Devices as MTP.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8GXd.jpg)

When attempting to update the driver from there, it can't find the necessary MTP driver, and when updating manually from the list of drivers I can't find any driver for MTP.

After having searched online, it seems very hard to find a solution, since everyone with this problem has internet access and it seems the issue is resolved with Windows Update installing the driver, but sadly this isn't an option for me (I **can** use a flash drive to download files on another computer and transfer to this one).

[This is the Windows version I'm using.](https://i.imgur.com/lrZDhDZ)

Is there any way to install the suitable MTP driver on this computer without connecting to the internet?

Comment: You might already have the required software. See if you can execute this [installation guide](https://www.droidviews.com/fix-mtp-driver-installation-on-windows-10/).

Comment: This raises the question: are you allowed to “sneaker-net” files to this computer; i.e., download files from the Internet on some other computer, and then bring them in to work on a flash drive (or a diskette, or whatever)?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thanks for the guide Harry, I hadn't tried some of the things on there. But wpdmtp.inf doesn't seem to be present on the computer, and the other solutions didn't work. I've also edited the post with more info, as Scott suggested.

Comment: Any luck on solving this issue? I have tried everything in all installation guides I could find but no luck.

Comment: I ended up getting internet access on the computer, before that I wasn't able to solve the issue either :/